# Can't return varbinary datatype from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, varbinary

I call a stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC @Varbinary = [Procedure] @Param1='test',@Param2='test',@OutputParam = @Output OUTPUT
```

Which goes to this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Procedure]
    @Param1 VARCHAR(50), @Param2 VARCHAR(32), @Output VARBINARY(128) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Param1 += @Param2

    SET @Output = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128),HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@Param1),2)

    --SELECT @Output
    RETURN

END    

GO
```

It returns 0x00000000. If I select a value directly from the procedure, it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_Proc
(
    @Param1 VARCHAR(50),
    @Param2 VARCHAR(32),
    @OutputParam VARBINARY(128) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @OutputParam = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Param1+@Param2),2)

    SELECT @OutputParam

END    
GO

DECLARE @Output VARBINARY(128)
EXEC usp_Proc @Param1='test', @Param2='test', @OutputParam = @Output OUTPUT
SELECT @Output
```

Output -

```
----------------------------------------------
0x125D6D03B32C84D492747F79CF0BF6E179D287F34138

----------------------------------------------
0x125D6D03B32C84D492747F79CF0BF6E179D287F34138
```